# Cannot bind to port 8080. It is probably taken by another application or you don't have enough privileges

Tags: apache, xampp

I deleted my XAMPP from the applications folder(without uninstalling) and installed it again then I tried to change my apache port 8080 after that this problem showed up 'Cannot bind to port 8080. It is probably taken by another application or you don't have enough privileges'

I tried to fix it by uninstalling and installing again it didn't work then I deleted cache files of XAMMP with some sudo code but it didn't work anyway

Answer (score -2):

in windows to check what ports applications are running on, open command prompt as admin and type "netstat -a -b"

stop whatever application is running on port 8080

Comment: my laptop is a mac
can I do it on the MacBook?

Comment: is your MacBook running windows ?

Comment: nope, it is not

Comment: well then you will not be able to execute a windows command, what operating system are you running, Linux ?